# Are zombies finite?

Tags: state-of-decay

Undead Labs has stated that *State of Decay* has a finite number of survivors and supplies. Does the game also have a finite (but very high) number of zombies in it as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On tab Mechanics of [Zombies in the SoD Wikia](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Zombies) you can read:

> In larger affect is a Hoard system, over time, base and outpost
>   **activity will cause zombies to spawn** in the region around the base, if
>   the problem is not dealt with, such as clearing out infestations, a
>   hoard will attack the base and attempt to destroy it.

If zombies spawn when there is activity, is possible to conclude that whenever there is activity zombies will spawn, causing them to be infinite.
In addition the game would lose the fun if there were no more zombies.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not positive, but I believe the Zeds are the only thing in the environment that is "infinite". Cars and weapons are definitely finite.
You can use the radio operator to "spawn" or generate specific supplies, (ammo, medicine, etc) often showing up in buildings already searched, but the number of times you can practically do that in the game is not infinite.
Zombies, however, seem to continually show up out of no where wherever that is player activity, even in cleared areas.